# IE onpropertychange, how to distinguish from real input and set value from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to listen to user input event in an input bar, so I used `onpropertychange` in IE:

```
input.onpropertychange = function(){
    // do something
};
```

but if I set the value of that input in JavaScript, the event will be fired too:

```
input.value = "test";
```

How could I distinguish them?

Comment: Keep in mind `onpropertychange` is *not* cross-browser.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yeah, I'm just facing the problem with IE right now. I'm using `input` event for other browsers

Comment: Store a flag in either the element properties or in a scoped var, set it to `true` before editing the value with JS and to `false` after you're done, then just check against it in the beginning of the handler function and `return;` if the condition doesn't match your requirement. Not a very clean solution, but when it comes to IE, I'd consider it pretty clean.

Comment: Note also that `onpropertychange` doesn't fire in IE where the value is changed using the delete or backspace keys, or for text that is selected and removed by pressing ctrl+x (cut). You may be better off to use the change even, as it's universally supported and has reasonably consistent behaviour for text input elements.